# jQuery blur event fires multiple times when two inputs involved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically created table with `<tr> <td> <inputs>`, problem is, when I click first `<td>` input and I click on to the next td input, jquery blur event fires multiple times. Even after using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`, I couldn't able to prevent the multiple firing on blur event and also I used flag set to false to prevent the firing, but I couldn't.
 Is there any other way to solve this problem?

```
for(var i=0;i< data.supplierdetails.length;i++){
var j = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + 100000000).toString().substring(1);
supplierdetailshtml += '<tr data-id="'+j+'">';
var description = data.supplierdetails[i].description;
supplierdetailshtml+= '<td><input type="text" name="rawproductname[]" id="rawproductname" value ="'+description+'" class="form-control rawproductname" readonly="true"/></td>';
supplierdetailshtml+= '<td><input type="text" name="hsncode[]" id="hsncode" class="form-control hsncode"/></td>';
var quantity = data.supplierdetails[i].quantity;
supplierdetailshtml+= '<td><input type="text" name="rawproductquantity[]" id="rawproductquantity_'+j+'" value ="'+quantity+'" class="form-control rawproductquantity" readonly="true"/></td>';
var unitcode = data.supplierdetails[i].unitcode;
supplierdetailshtml+= '<td><input type="text" name="rawproductunitcode[]" id="rawproductunitcode" value ="'+unitcode+'" class="form-control rawproductunitcode" readonly="true"/></td>';
supplierdetailshtml+='<td><input type="text" name="rawproductrate[]" id="rawproductrate_'+j+'" value="0.00" class="form-control rawproductrate"/></td>';
supplierdetailshtml+='<td><input type="text" name="rawproductprice[]" id="rawproductprice_'+j+'" value="0.00" class="form-control rawproductprice"/></td>';
supplierdetailshtml+= '<td><input type="text" name="rawproductgst[]" id="rawproductgst_'+j+'" value="0.00" class="form-control rawproductgst"/></td></tr>';                                 
}


$(document).on('blur','.rawproductrate',function(event){
    debugger;

    var tr_id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    //alert("Data ID"+tr_id);
    var rawproductquantity = $("#rawproductquantity_"+tr_id).val();
    //alert("Raw Product Quantity"+rawproductquantity);
    var rawproductrate = $("#rawproductrate_"+tr_id).val();
    //alert("Raw Product rate"+rawproductrate);
    if (rawproductrate==0 || rawproductrate=="") {
        alert("Raw Product Rate Cannot be Zero");
    }
    var rawproductprice = parseFloat(rawproductrate*rawproductquantity).toFixed(2);                 
    if(isNaN(rawproductprice) || rawproductprice==""){
        var rawproductprice_decimal = parseFloat(rawproductprice || 0).toFixed(2);
        $("#rawproductprice_"+tr_id).val(rawproductprice_decimal);
    }
    $("#rawproductprice_"+tr_id).val(rawproductprice);
    $('.rawproductrate').off('blur');
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;                   
});
```

Comment: Please share the js fiddle.....